# How to hide private class declaration on doxygen documentation

Tags: documentation, doxygen, doxywizard, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

```
class class1:
public:
...
private:
class impl; //the class that i wanna hide
std::unique_ptr<impl> impl_;
```

//my doxygen file:

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES

EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO

EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO

EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO

EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES

EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO

HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES

HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO

Answer (score 1):

Changing my doxygen file made it work!

```
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = NO
```